# Weibo missing oauth_callback_confirmed

Tags: weibo, sinaweibo

I believe I have managed to register an app within weibo (translating everything through Google) and I have started the Oauth process (1.0) and get back a token and secret at the request_token stage. However I don't get an oauth_callback_confirmed=true parameter. This is a **business** application and I haven't submitted the app for approval but (because I don't speak Chinese) am not sure if I actually have to. If anyone can help that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use Oauth v2 which worked fine. Be-ware you need to set a valid redirect URL which is under the Settings menu on the App area. I also find that during the Chinese evening time I can never access the API documentation.